# How to apply OR logic to Team Query - TFS2008

Tags: tfs

How do I correctly apply OR in a Team Explorer 2008 query? According to msdn OR should apply to the immediately previous clause and the current clause only, but it seems to apply to 'all of the above' and the current clause.

eg

Work Item in Bug,Task
And State In Resolved, Closed
And Title Contains A
OR Title contains B

resolves to

(Work Item in Bug,Task
And State In Resolved, Closed
And Title Contains A)
OR (Title contains B)

when what I want (and what it apparently should be) is

Work Item in Bug,Task
And State In Resolved, Closed
And (Title Contains A
OR Title contains B)

Is there any way to overide the logic with brackets?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be using brackets to group your clauses, to ensure the correct order of operations.  This is built in the query builder UI:

[image]

That little pink section is the grouping (aka brackets) I have already put around those two clauses.  You group clauses by ticking off the checkboxes, then clicking the little button at the top that will become enabled once you tick off some checkboxes.

Comment: See my 'answer' below. Is the a way around this, or until we can upgrade everything to VS2013 (with which we have serious upgrade problems), do I just have to put up with this as a VS 'bug'?

Answer (score 0):

Dylan,

Sadly VS2008 doesn't offer those columns in 'view query' view:

[image]